# how to retrieve result from cypher rest API through getResultSet() function

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

```
<?php
require("phar://neo4jphp.phar");

$client      = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
$queryString = "START n=node:node_auto_index(name="ashish"),m=node:node_auto_index(city="bhilai"),p=node:node_auto_andex(school="bhilai") RETURN n,m,p";
$query       = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
$result      = $query->getResultSet();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['x']->getproperty('name'), $row['y']->getproperty('city'), $row['z']->getproperty('school');
}

?>
```

This is not working as expected, its giving the same property, i.e.: name

Comment: Thanks @tijoene  i  cannot  figure  out  how  to  do  it  multiline

Comment: are the quotes in your query escaped? I cannot see you defining `x,y,z` anywhere? Please use `return n as x` etc.

Comment: Cypher   doc  says  when  multiple  colmuns  are  returned  eavh  one  is  asseces  be  using  x,y,z  as  associative  arrays  in  result  row  variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning columns "n,m,p" in your query. Those are the names of the columns in the result set as well.

Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  echo $row['n']->getproperty('name'), $row['m']->getproperty('city'), $row['p']->getproperty('school');
}
```

Docs for this at https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-and-gremlin-queries

The docs use "x" and "y" because those are the names of the columns in the example query. From the docs: "If multiple columns of data are returned, each one can be accessed in the row by name." The names come from the `RETURN` clause of the query.

Comment: Thanks  for  the  answer, i  kind  of  skipped  that   thing , thanks  again